# Quero receber um xml do webservice no android

Tags: android, web-service, xml, url, get

Já tentei de tudo, usando o `HttpURLConnection` , com o `HttpClient` que está deprecidado, essas duas opção não terminam, param no `BufferedReader`. Já tentei usar `AsyncTask` com o `doInBackground` , mas da erro:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Já coloquei o a permissão de acesso a internet. Segue abaixo o que estou tentando fazer.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(s);            
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));                
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();                
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            System.out.println("----------------------"+stringBuilder.toString());
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: se deu NetworkOnMainThreadException então a asynctask está errada...esse erro ocorre justamente quando tenta fazer conexão na UI thread (resumidamente a activity).

Comment: Você tem mais alguma informação do erro?

Comment: Você usou a AsyncTask de forma errada se deu o erro `NetworkOnMainThreadException`